# Regex for identifying a mergefield in an IF condition used in word

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Am able to find the megefields in a word document using the following regex

```
EX: <<SAMPLEMERGEFIELD>>

private static readonly Regex instructionRegEx =
        new Regex(
                    @"^[\s]*MERGEFIELD[\s]+(?<name>[#\w]*){1}               
                        [\s]*(\\\*[\s]+(?<Format>[\w]*){1})?                
                        [\s]*(\\b[\s]+[""]?(?<PreText>[^\\]*){1})?        
                        [\s]*(\\f[\s]+[""]?(?<PostText>[^\\]*){1})?",
                    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

how to find the mergefield which is inside an IF condition just like this

```
{=IF(<<MERGEFIELD>> >= 100,10,0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is SingleLine already, cant you just do "if\s?(.*?.*?)"